# react-waypoint onEnter/onLeave is not giving value

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

i was recently trying out react-waypoint to hide and reveal a div. This code successfully hides the div when it hits the waypoint is "inside" when it is onEnter. When it is inside it turns isInView to true which toggles my div to be true and reveal itself. The code of onLeave might be at fault here but when i console logged the current position and it was below the waypoint( or in my case when i scroll up from the shown div it is consoled logged as below) the code did not turn into false.

thanks for helping I appreciate it a lot !

```
class WhenInView extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isInView: false
        };
        this.onEnter = this.onEnter.bind(this);
        this.onLeave = this.onLeave.bind(this);
    }


      onEnter({ currentPosition }){
        console.log(currentPosition)
        if (currentPosition === Waypoint.inside){

            this.setState({
                isInView: true
            });
        }
    }
        onLeave({ currentPosition }){
        console.log(currentPosition)
        if (this.currentPosition === Waypoint.below){  

            this.setState({
                isInView: false
            });
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
            <Waypoint onEnter = {this.onEnter} onLeave ={this.onLeave}></Waypoint>
            {this.props.children({ isInView: this.state.isInView})}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default WhenInView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the problem is you are using `this.currentPosition` instead of `currentPosition` and you have no state variable of `currentPosition` so Every time it returns undefined and your condition always evaluates to false so the control is not even going inside the loop so that is the problem. 
 This should be your function for onLeave:

```
onLeave({ currentPosition }){
    console.log(currentPosition)
    if (currentPosition === Waypoint.below){  

        this.setState({
            isInView: false
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply aravindreddy. I just set this.currentPosition back to currentPosition but it is still not working. While i was reading the documentation on the readMe by the react team they said that current position is the current waypoint it is at. I am just recently implementing this new dependency and i'm having trouble with the correct syntax. how would you set the condition with current position?

Comment: because when i console log if the current position is either inside or below when it is below on the onLeave it does console log it like so .             onLeave({ currentPosition }){
        console.log(currentPosition,"this logs below")
        if (currentPosition === Waypoint.below){ 
            console.log("this consoled because i am ontop of the div") 
            this.setState({
                isInView: false
            });
            console.log("setstate", this.setState)
        }

Comment: try adding `console.log(currentPosition)` inside the if condition and check if that statement is getting executed or not so that you can at least know control is coming inside the loop and can you provide the link to the docs

Comment: iam not getting you point so your program control is going inside the loop ?

Comment: i just tried to look up what program control meant but i could not find it. can you explain what program control is? ahah sorry im not really familiar with this dependency and react yet

Comment: and i did add console.log inside of the if condition and it is getting executed

Comment: so now your isInView variable is set to false right ?

Comment: i just console.logged setState and it was a call back function saying setstate in currentposition ƒ (partialState, callback) {
  !(typeof..... and while i was reading the document for this console.log it also said ////  * Sets a subset of the state. Always use this to mutate
 * state. You should treat `this.state` as immutable.
 * There is no guarantee that `this.state` will be immediately updated .  I am fairly confused on why i cant console log this.isInView it turns up to be undefined

Comment: the isInView variable is set as false within the constructor and it does set it to true when i am Onenter but when i go away from the waypoint it console.logs that the current position is === to waypoint.below. I still cannot figure out how to console.log isInView to see it's state i even tried console.logging it onEnter but it must be wrong syntax on my end

Comment: actually i figured out the problem, everything was working fine i guess??  there is still something weird when i try to go below the waypoint but ill try out some configurations. When i tried out waypoint.above and added more divs it works

Comment: Thats weird however if everything is solved accept the answer so that it helps others